# how to display data dynamically to link tag by using angular ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

This is my code

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log) {


 $scope.gridOptions = {};

   $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
         { name: 'firstName',cellTemplate:'<a ng-model=firstName></a>'},
         { name: 'lastName'},
         { name: 'Hyperlink',
             cellTemplate:'<div>' +
                       '  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Click me</a>' +
                       '</div>' }
       ];

 $scope.gridOptions.data = [
    {
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "company": "Enormo",
        "employed": true
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Lorraine",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "company": "Comveyer",
        "employed": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "company": "Fuelton",
        "employed": false
    }
];
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
</div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my plunker:- http://plnkr.co/edit/WFSbpkYv91af3uAbBnIp?p=preview

In the above code display firstname without link format.but i want to display firsname column data in link format.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of cellTemplate that will display the name

```
cellTemplate:'<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">{{ row.entity.firstName }}</a>'
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/F5PS4nCzLkywnSzazMNx

Regards,
Eric

Comment: You're welcome. If it's work like this do not hesitate to approve the answer.